# how to focus a particular section of a page in php while redirecting to the same page

Tags: php

i am posting a form to the same page using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` after form submission i require to focus (scroll to) the footer of page where the form is located; tried header call outside condition block, prompted an error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS", and if i put header call inside condition block. redirection works and also focuses the desired portion but rest of the php code does not work

```
<?php 
    $popupMessage = '';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);

        if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($message)){
            //code for sending mail
            $popupMessage = 'Email Sent Successfully';
            }

        else{
            $popupMessage = 'Please fill in all the fields';
        }
    // header('Location: test.php#footer'); 
    }   

?>

<html>
   <center> 
        <div style="width:100%; height:1200px;"><h1>please scroll down</h1></div>

        <div id="footer" style="border:1px solid grey">

            <span><?php echo $popupMessage ?></span>

            <form id="form-location" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">     
                    <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"></p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email"></p>
                    <p><textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea></p>
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
            </form>

        </div>
 </center>
</html>
```

Comment: here is the code i tried <?php header('Location: samepage.php#elt') ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your redirection is executing unconditionally. Put it inside the condition where you process your form if it's submitted like so:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
  // Process the form normally.
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '#myElt');
  exit;
}
```

The `Location` header will create a new request, so this solution won't work if you want to keep the post data. What you can do instead is change your `form action`:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>#footer" method="post">
```

Comment: that is true i've placed redirection code outside the condition but if i put that inside , the entire script above it gets bypassed if((filter_has_var(INPUT_POST , 'submit'))){ //form processing                                                            header('Location: samepage.php#myElt');}

Comment: if i put header call inside condition block. redirection works and also focuses the desired portion but rest of the php code does not work. i've added actual code as well. Please enlighten me